# Searching network drive without indexing - win xp

Tags: windows-xp, search, windows-search, file-search

I believe someone else asked that question in relation to Windows 7 but if I want to search a network drive in Win XP, is there a way to do it without the need to index the files?

Answer (score 4):

If you right click the mapped/network drive, click properties, then uncheck "allow indexing..." you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

When I need to search a network location I just pop out to a command window and use `DIR /S`.  It does not use the indexes, only searches the file names (not contents) and I have found it to be reasonably fast.  The `/S` switch will search subfolders for you.  You can use multiple wildcards if needed to expand or refine your search (`*` for any number of characters, `?` for one character) and it doesn't suffer from issues with trying to include or exclude things like parentheses, the way Windows search does.  I also use the `/B` switch to get a more compact listing (no summaries between subfolders).